# How to start a REPL at a point of exception in Cider

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, nrepl

I am trying to use Clojure with emacs and cider for  a project of mine, and often exceptions occur while executing my code. When an exception occurs, cider provides me a stack trace, but often that is not sufficient to quickly identify what went wrong. I am looking for some way to make CIDER initialize a REPL when the exception occurs, that will allow me to examine the values of locals at the point of occurring of exception and perhaps even change some of the values and continue execution from that point. Is it possible with Clojure, Emacs and Cider?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, such feature is not available neither in CIDER nor in other IDEs (Cursive, LightTable).

The most you can do is to insert a [breakpoint](https://cider.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging/) before erroneous form and, when debugger has popped up, inspect locals there.